# PDF file downloaded open in Acrobat Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, migradoc

I'm downloading a PDF file using migradoc in my asp.net application :

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports_" + _title + ext);

 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfRenderer.Save(ms, false);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Read(buffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the PDF is opened in acrobat reader aswell as being downloaded to my computer.
I would like if it would only be downloaded to my computer but not opened in acrobat reader.

Any help is appreciated, I couldn't find any information related specifically to this problem.

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: Google chrome, lastest version - Version 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: for the record, the answer of deleting one of the 2 reponse.clear()  was not working

Comment: Your browser chooses what to do with downloads. Check your browser settings, it likely has nothing to do with what's happening on the server.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I cleaned up my auto open on download.
You can propose it as a answer if you want. ill accept it